# How to connect My Visual Studio 2012 Project and my friend's project to the same pc

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I want to connect same pc to my project and my friend's project. Please keep in mind that we don't need the TFS.

Comment: How does one connect PC to a project, never mind the same or different?

Comment: have a  another parts in my friend pc, i want to connect my and my friend's project with main pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subversion tools like Git,Tortoise SVN etc..

These tool gives so many options so that you can easily manage the source code across team members

you can know more about git [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software))